# Get In App Purchase View Controller to remember what has been purchased

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

My In-App Purchase View Controller needs to remember which items have been bought.  Currently, every time the View Controller is visited the app doesn't remember what has been purchased.  So you have to make the In-App Purchase again, which then will let you know it has already been purchased, and restores the purchase.

I need it to not go thru that whole song and dance if someone has already bought the In-App Purchase.

Do I use NSUserDefaults for this?  And if so, am I saving the receipt number and then matching that up with something to verify then show the In-App Purchase that has been purchased?

Let me know if you need me to post any code, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `NSUserDefaults`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

For more details check it out : [raywenderlich - introduction-to-in-app-purchases](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)

Comment: Yup, it made me wait a couple minutes earlier

Answer (score 1):

If you have a server for your application then you can save it on server that user has purchased this item. So that even if user delete the app, user can get his In-app status.

But if you are not using any server than you can store purchase credential in NSUserDefaults.